# From Reflection Spectrum to Preceived Color

Tags: visible-light, reflection, color-charge

I have a reflection curve over the visible spectrum (350nm to 700nm) of a sample. Now, I am interested to know what preceived color one would see ?

[image]

Is it possible to go from the reflection spectrum to a precieved color (like a color in the RGB space) ? If yes, how ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's providing the illumination?  The sun, a fluorescent bulb, or ...  If you used monochromatic light, that's all you'd get back.  But even if you specify the spectrum of the source and calculated the reflections, perceptions of color are context- and contrast-dependent.  A white shape on a green background might be perceived as bluish or pinkish.

Comment: @BertBarrois Thank you for your comment. The incident light is white (sun-light).